# all routes sends me to welcome blade

Tags: php, laravel

*those are my routes and all send me to welcome blade; for example, if I try to go to about. blade it end up in welcome blade*

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'],function(){
Route::get('/','Room_randring_welcom@index')->name('post')->middleware('setLocale');

 });

 Route::get('/about', function () {
 return view('aboutUs');
 });
 Route::get('/rooms', function () {
 return view('Room');
 });
 Route::get('/contact','Email_send@contact');

 Route::post('/contact','Email_send@Contact_Submit')->name('Contact.submit');
 Route::get('/Gallery', function () {
 return view('Gallery');
 });
 Route::get('/room_detail', function () {
 return view('room_details');
 });
```

Comment: Use ```php artisan cache:clear``` and ```php artisan route:cache```

Comment: You no need to make `route:cache` in local development - just clear cache

Comment: Provide some more information about the request you make, please.

Comment: In local development you just need to clear route also like this: `php artisan route:clear`.

In production you should run `php artisan route:cache`.

Comment: @AnisurRahman I appreciate your help, it worked perfectly